# How to Convert excel to .plist and .sqlite on Mac?

Tags: excel, sqlite, plist

Is there any tool that can convert Excel sheets into .plist or .sqlite quickly when developing iOS and Android Apps?

Comment: The three file-formats you mentioned are not directly comparable. What are you wanting to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: We need to convert some datas which are created by Excel into .sqlite format ,so that we can use in iOS and Android development. I have tried an app named [Excel2Plist Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1173584935?mt=12) , which can deal with .xlsx and .xls files very well!

Answer (score 1):

Check following [app](https://itunes.apple.com/tw/app/convert-excel-to-.plist-.sqlite/id1013339698?mt=12).
There are many online tools which also support this conversion. In that case you need to `save as` your `.xls` file into [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have founded an app named [Excel2Plist Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1173584935?mt=12)
 , which can deal with .xlsx and .xls files very well!